# Port reassignment in Java: JADE with MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab

I'm working on JADE (Java Agent DEvelopment Framework) for the connection with MATLAB. I'm using eclipse IDE emulator. I'm able to run the JADE agent with a port 1234, and get the output. But next time when I try to run, it does not work.

If I try to refresh JADE agent, it throws binding error that port is already in used. 
(1) Is there a way by which I can keep the agent alive and can call java program multiple times (same terminal)? OR
(2) The agent can reset or kill the assigned port and can assign the same port to the new instance of the called program.

Any help is appreciated!